# how to retain session when sending second request in curl php?

Tags: php, node.js, session, curl, session-cookies

My problem is that when I synchronize data from PHP to node js 1st time I logged in to the node.js application. But after logging in when I sending data on second request the session is not sending with curl request hence it is showing that 'not logged in'.

Its my loggin curl code:

```
$data_string = json_encode(['userid' => $user_name, 'password' => $password]);
$URL = $url;     

$ch = curl_init('http://192.168.1.16:8000/auth/login');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                 
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

And it is sending data Curl code:

```
$data_string = json_encode(['import_export' =>$json]);                                                                                   

https://stackoverflow.com/users
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://192.168.1.16:8000/api/all',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
        )
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Is this a cookie-based login? Then go read up on how to make cURL handle those properly.

Comment: I use node session to store login information in nodejs API.

Comment: Nodejs doesn't handle session cookies, Express does.

Comment: Yes I use express to create the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell cURL to use cookies:

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
```

This way the default Node/Express session cookie based authentication should work since session cookie will be saved upon login and sent with subsequent requests.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php